# Joining animated model to a quick fire effect

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

I have been trying to join a quickfire effect sphere in evee with a model I finally found a way to animate but each time the model moves the flame does not follow it.

Is there a way to join the sphere (which is the fire mesh) and the smoke domain to the main model and make them follow the animation?
Also, will the fire domain box still keep showing when I render?

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you tried copy location constraint?

Comment: No.  Never heard of it.  Can you tell me how it is done pls?

Answer (score 0):

- select fire object
- go to object constraints in properties panel
- add copy location constraint
- select target object

  [image: copy location constraint]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried as you suggested and met partial success.  The fire constrains itself to the golem but not in its body but above it.  I had to constrain it to a spine bone of the armature as well to obtain this result.  I also tried inverting the z-axis but it went 2 down.     Added photos in the main question. Any way I can center the flame pls?

Comment: @ronin074 you need to have object origins in the right place, they seem off to me :)

Comment: Control a / transform all should do it then.   I will try as soon as I have a chance and let you know. ty